# How do I group by unknown/random tags?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am collecting signal strength of bluetooth devices. Measurments include RSSI and a device's MAC address (as a tag):

```
time                tag               value
----                ---               -----
1553770236937486564 13:e4:XX:XX:XX:XX 50
1553770237065321631 49:24:XX:XX:XX:XX 33
1553770237065337933 36:8b:XX:XX:XX:XX 45
```

My (Grafana) graph should show a line based on each MAC's changing signal strength. The time period I'd display is relatively short, therefore retention is also quite short.

Since devices come and go I cannot formulate queries that group by MAC address beforehand. Is there a way to formulate something like a meta query resulting in as many different colored lines as there are MAC addresses in the chosen timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `repeat` option of Grafana:

- edit graph
- `General` tab
- `Repeat`: for each value of `your MAC tag`

EDIT: After your comment, here's another option:

Say your tag is `mac`, you'll add:

- `GROUP BY` `tag(mac)`
- `ALIAS BY` `$tag_mac` (or if you need more text: `MAC-address: $tag_mac`)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am afraid it doesn't solve it. I successfully created a variable which contains all MACs but I cannot come up with query that draws lines for all MACs in one chart. The repeat option you refer to would create individual charts for each MAC address.

Comment: @PiEnthusiast I've added another option, you're right, I've misread your question.

Comment: Regrettably, `SELECT mean("value") FROM "btle" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY tag(mac) fill(null)` doesn't work.

Comment: @PiEnthusiast are you using Grafana selectors (dropdowns and the like) or typing `influx` query? It's a completely different syntax! For instance, in influx you would type: `SELECT mean("value") FROM "btle" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "mac" fill(null)`, there is no `tag()`. Use the Grafana selectors as much as possible, and click `Query inspector` if you want the real query sent to `influx`